# change selected item color in ionic listview

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework

Hi i am new to ionic framework and css. I have a listview with some items. I want to change selected item list color. 
This is my code

```
<ion-list show-delete="shouldShowDelete" can-swipe="true">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="wishlist in wishListItems" class="item-thumbnail-left">
    <img src='data:image/png;base64,{{wishlist.wishlistItemImage}}'/>

    <h2>{{wishlist.wishlistItemName}}</h2>
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive icon ion-trash-a" ng-click="deleteWishlistItem(wishlist.wishlistId)">
    </ion-option-button>


  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And i want to know index of selected item. 
Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <style>
   .deleted{
      color:red;
    }
  .notdeleted{
    color:green;
   }
 </style>
  <ion-list show-delete="shouldShowDelete" can-swipe="true">
  <ion-item ng-repeat="(key,val) in wishListItems" class="item-thumbnail-left">

  <h2 ng-class="val.deleted ? 'deleted' : 'notdeleted'">{{val.wishlistItemName}}</h2>
  <ion-option-button class="button-assertive icon ion-trash-a" ng-click="deleteWishlistItem(key)">delete
</ion-option-button>
```

the `deleteWishlistItem()` method will be

```
$scope.deleteWishlistItem = function(key){
   $scope.wishListItems[key].deleted = true;
}
```